# How can I find the task_size for my 64-bit linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, 64-bit

I want to know how much space is reserved for the kernel and how much for the user process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0000000000000000 - 00007fffffffffff (=47 bits) user space, different per mm
hole caused by [48:63] sign extension
ffff800000000000 - ffff87ffffffffff (=43 bits) guard hole, reserved for hypervisor
ffff880000000000 - ffffc7ffffffffff (=64 TB) direct mapping of all phys. memory
ffffc80000000000 - ffffc8ffffffffff (=40 bits) hole
ffffc90000000000 - ffffe8ffffffffff (=45 bits) vmalloc/ioremap space
ffffe90000000000 - ffffe9ffffffffff (=40 bits) hole
ffffea0000000000 - ffffeaffffffffff (=40 bits) virtual memory map (1TB)
... unused hole ...
ffffec0000000000 - fffffc0000000000 (=44 bits) kasan shadow memory (16TB)
... unused hole ...
ffffff0000000000 - ffffff7fffffffff (=39 bits) %esp fixup stacks
... unused hole ...
ffffffff80000000 - ffffffffa0000000 (=512 MB)  kernel text mapping, from phys 0
ffffffffa0000000 - ffffffffff5fffff (=1525 MB) module mapping space
ffffffffff600000 - ffffffffffdfffff (=8 MB) vsyscalls
ffffffffffe00000 - ffffffffffffffff (=2 MB) unused hole
```

The direct mapping covers all memory in the system up to the highest
memory address (this means in some cases it can also include PCI memory
holes).

vmalloc space is lazily synchronized into the different PML4 pages of
the processes using the page fault handler, with init_level4_pgt as
reference.

Current X86-64 implementations only support 40 bits of address space,
but we support up to 46 bits. This expands into MBZ space in the page tables.

So, in short user space gets 247 bytes = 128TiB, and kernel gets 512MiB. The rest of the address space goes to various parts of the system, along with a few unusable holes.

You may also read about 64 bit systems here .
[x86_64 Canonical address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Canonical_form_addresses)

Answer (score 5):

**TASK_SIZE** defined in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.7/source/arch/arm/include/asm/memory.h#L40, and it can be accessed with the following code. Please compile it as a kernel module.

---

### TASK_SIZE.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/memory.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Open Source");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Module for TASK_SIZE");

static int __init find_task_size_init(void);
static void __exit find_task_size_exit(void);

static int
__init find_task_size_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Memory TASK_SIZE: 0x%lx\n", TASK_SIZE);
    return 0;
}

static void
__exit find_task_size_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "module exits ok !\n");
}

module_init(find_task_size_init);
module_exit(find_task_size_exit);
```

---

### Makefile

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    # call from kernel build system
    lifo-objs := main.o
    obj-m     := TASK_SIZE.o
else
    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD       := $(shell pwd)
modules:
    echo $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) LDDINC=$(PWD)/../include modules
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) LDDINC=$(PWD)/../include modules
endif

clean:  
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend *.mod.o .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions *.markers *.symvers modules.order

depend .depend dep:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -M *.c > .depend

ifeq (.depend,$(wildcard .depend))
    include .depend
endif
```

---

```
# dmesg -k -w          # In the first console shell

[ 2570.156990] Memory TASK_SIZE: 0x7ffffffff000
[ 2573.164671] module exits ok !
```

---

```
# make                 # In the second console shell
# insmod TASK_SIZE.ko
# rmmod TASK_SIZE
```